# Plugin cannot find Jenkins static resource

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

This plugin needs to read an xml data store and parse certain elements of it

```
    File file = new File(Functions.getResourcePath()+"/plugin/company-deploy-jenkins-plugin/release.xml");
    boolean fileExists = file.exists();
    if (fileExists) {
        LOGGER.info("Found the file");
    }
    Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(file));
```

However, I can't seem to be able to access the file. if(fileExists) evaluates to false although the file is available at http://%JenkinsHost%:%Port%/plugin/company-deploy-jenkins-plugin/release.xml and the file is available locally directly under the src/main/webapp folder.

I am trying to follow KK's advice on handling Jenkins static resources as described here: http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/ANN-Referring-to-static-resources-from-your-plugin-td4490655.html.

Upon checking the file path via file.toString(), I get /static/4874107b/plugin/company-deploy-jenkins-plugin/release.xml.

Doing any work on the object document returns a null pointer exception with message (No such file or directory).

Any ideas?

Comment: First thing would be, check what `file.toString()` produces, and verify it makes sense, and add that to the question too while you're at it.

Comment: added info on file.toString()

Comment: Well, that is an absolute path. Copy-paste it to `ls -l` shell command (or whatever) and see what prints.

Comment: I think you need something more, such as location of Jenkins directory...

Comment: yeah, when I hard code the path to the resource on the file system, it works fine. /tools/jenkins/jenkins_home/plugins/company-deploy-jenkins-plugin/release.xml... However, I want to try to avoid hardcoding and make use of Jenkins' caching mechanism

Comment: Perhaps you have a missing/bad JENKINS_HOME env variable? Try creating a dummy test job, add shell script build step, and put command `echo JENKINS_HOME: $JENKINS_HOME` there, and see what it prints.

Comment: That's not the issue either; JENKINS_HOME is defined and returns the correct value. For now, I hardcoded the path on disk and it seems to be working. Ideally, I want to remove that hardcoding in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Jenkins.getInstance().getPlugin("plugin-name").getWrapper().baseResourceURL.getFile()
```

--> this will return the /src/main/webapp location

From this location, you will be able to find your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jenkins.model.Jenkins` to assist you:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;
...
String releaseXmlUrl = Jenkins.getInstance().getRootUrl() + "plugin/company-deploy-jenkins-plugin/release.xml";
```

Or if you're attempting this from a [Descriptor](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Descriptor.html) in your plugin, you can make this more resilient to changes in the short-name of your plugin like so:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;
...
String releaseXmlUrl = Jenkins.getInstance().getRootUrl() + "plugin/" + getPlugin().getShortName() + "/release.xml";
```